# Qt SDK on Windows: how to use Assistant

Tags: windows, qt

After installing Qt SDK on Windows, I don't see any Help item in the Qt SDK menu. QtCreator\bin directory contains assistant.exe, and Documentation directory contains *.qch files. Is it possible to create a shortcut showing Qt Assistant with Qt SDK reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these .qch files by going to the menu Edit > Preferences > Documentation > Add...

You should only need to do that once.